# В том <...>, что

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы

Очевидно, что можно сказать *тот поезд, что сейчас проехал.* "Что" тут вместо "который". А правильно я понимаю, что следующее словосочетание со "что" уже будет неверным?

> в том поезде, что я сейчас ехал (в котором)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно понимаете. А. Зализняк [говорил](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=_6ZCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA669&dq=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiB0MTs7ZPrAhXOxIsKHaQtBSgQ6AEwB3oECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9&f=false):

> Употребления *что* в такой роли (т. е. вместо *который*) строго ограничено
> именительным и винительным падежами.

Comment: Спасибо, grizzly! Я рад, что чутьё не подвело. :)

Comment: А как же *где эта барышня, что я влюблён,* grizzly?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой "... , в которую я влюблён". "Которую" здесь больше похоже на винительный падеж, чем на какой-либо другой. Хотя "... , что я люблю" звучит аккуратнее. Впрочем, я не уверен, насколько эта строчка в песне соответствует литературной / разговорной / просторечной норме. Вряд ли в учебниках говорят о таком странном сочетании с формами страдательного залога.

Comment: Спасибо, grizzly, что прокомментировали)